# How to describe AWS / Google Cloud Platform experience for a Microsoft application?

Tags: resume, applications, qualification

I have specific project experience using AWS and Google Cloud Platform for hosting virtual instances and handling scalability, although I have not used Microsoft's version of the same service (Azure) on a project. On an application to Microsoft, what is the best way to display this experience? Should I get familiar with Azure enough to list it on my resume along with AWS and GCP, or just list something generic like "implemented DNS routing on a virtual machine to create a MEAN stack..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your experience not in any vendor-specific context, but instead as experience building applications for the cloud. That's not to say you shouldn't mention which vendors you've used-- rather, you want to emphasize your experience in building applications and architectures that are highly scalable.

Remember, Microsoft offers Linux on Azure as well. They're aiming to be a cloud services provider, not just a Windows cloud services provider. To do that they're going to need people like you.